# Boolean program in java giving error

Tags: java

This code is giving error dont know why? error is " constructor Boolean in class Boolean cannot be      applied to given type". I am running this code on jdk 7

```
class Boolean12
{

public static void main(String s[])

{
                       // this code is to assign boolean values in different form

Boolean c = new Boolean(null);
Boolean d = new Boolean("null");
Boolean e = new Boolean("TRue");
Boolean f = new Boolean(TRue);
Boolean g = new Boolean(true);




System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(f);
System.out.println(g);

}
}
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this...

Comment: Boolean only has two constructors: `Boolean(String)` & `Boolean(boolean)` ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#Boolean%28boolean%29

Answer (score 1):

In your class `Boolean` there is no matching constructors for any of these

```
Boolean c = new Boolean(null);
Boolean d = new Boolean("null");
Boolean e = new Boolean("TRue");
Boolean f = new Boolean(TRue);
Boolean g = new Boolean(true);
```

Then you can't do such initializations. Try to learn `Java`. There is a class name `Boolean` in `Java` why you want to create another?

Comment: sorry, i have edited my question .

Answer (score 0):

```
class Boolean
{

  public Boolean(Object object) {
        }

    public Boolean() {
       }

public static void main(String s[])

{

Boolean c = new Boolean(null);
Boolean d = new Boolean("null");
Boolean e = new Boolean("TRue");
Boolean f = new Boolean("TRue");
Boolean g = new Boolean(true);
Boolean h = new Boolean();



 System.out.println(c);
 System.out.println(d);
 System.out.println(e);
 System.out.println(f);
 System.out.println(g);
 System.out.println(h);
}
}
```

try this